# Задать определенное время в AlarmManager

Tags: android, java

Возникла проблема при вызове **Notification** в определенное время суток. 
**Notification** вызываю при помощи **AlarmManager**.
Когда задаю текущее время (System.currentTimeMillis()), проблем не возникает, все отлично запускается и выводится, но как только пытаюсь задать определенное, то бишь, точное время, ничего не происходит. Что подскажете? Как правильно задать время?

Рабочий вариант:

```
private void restartNotify(Context context) {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationMessage.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), contentIntent);
}
```

Не рабочий:

```
private void restartNotify(Context context) {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationMessage.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);
}
```

**Решил проблему. Вот реализация:**

```
 private void restartNotify(Context context) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationMessage.class);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);
    }
```

Прошу обратить внимание, кому интересно, что бы все заработало, нужно задать все пункты (год, месяц, день, часы, минуты, секунды, миллисекунды). Важный пункт **calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR OF DAY, 13);**. Если указать **Calendar.HOUR** вместо **Calendar.HOUR OF DAY** то время вместо 24-х часового формата, будет использовать 12-ти часовой, из-за чего время будет считаться указанным не верно (Если у вас на телефоне 24-х часовой формат)

Comment: long todayTime = nowCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
long tomorrowTime = todayTime + TimeUtils.MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY;  //+1 day

Может это натолкнет на какую-нибудь мысль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А можете проверить какое именно время вы получаете в calendar.getTimeInMillis()?
И попробуйте вместо обычного использовать григорианский календарь

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar()
```

Comment: @Nuclominus, Сделал вывод даты в TextView используя ваш вариант Calendar. (Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar()) и свой (Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()). Оба варианта выводят одинаковую верную дату и время. Выводит следующее: Mon Jun 09 13:32:33 EEST 2014. (Это и есть то время, когда я сделал вывод. Но почему-то с AlarmManager все равно ни один вариант не канает.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно 3 параметров. Можно упростить на Kotlin:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
```